# How to perform a read immediately after performing a write using RxAndroidBle?

Tags: android, rx-java2, rxandroidble

The RxAndroidBle examples provides an example for [how to perform a write after a read](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle#read-and-write-combined), but nothing about a read after a write. I tried to follow the procedure for performing a write after a read, but for my use case, but the flatMap where I perform a write returns an Observable with byte, so I can't access `RxBleConnection`

Answer (score 0):

After you `.establishConnection()`, insert `.doOnNext( connection -> savedConnection = connection)` and use the `savedConnection` for future operations.

Don't forget to `.dispose()` when done to release the connection (and also set `savedConnection = null`).